# Hibernate fetchtype lazy is loading the target object(table) be default?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I have a Hibernate Entity, I have manually defined a Ref Integrity on some condition in database, and it works fine for me to fetch the target entity.

The problem is that I have defined FetchType of that property as Lazy. So ideally it should only request when accessed. But when I fetch the parent entity it fetches the mapped entity as well.

Comment: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="WK_SUB_LG_CODE", referencedColumnName = "SUBLANGUAGECODE",updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="WK_LG_CODE", referencedColumnName = "LANGUAGECODE",updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
 public SubLanguage getSubLanguageByWkLgCode() {
  return subLanguageByWkLgCode;
 }

Comment: How did you know it fetch the mapped entity as well ?

Comment: Is the referenced entity part of a persistent object hierarchy, i.e. has subclasses?

Comment: @Mayura Nawarathne - I turned on show_sql feature, I could see two select statements while just fetching the parent entity.

Comment: @ThomasStets - Yes it has subclass as well, and it can be a part of some parent object as well. But the issue is, im not fetching this referenced object, just accessing parent object, still it loads. I have given FetchType as Lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some cases when hibernate can not use lazy loading, even if you tell it to do so. One case is a hierarchy of persistent objects.

When you specify lazy loading for a reference to another persistent object, hibernate creates a dynamic proxy object, which only gets populated from database when you actually try to access any of its attributes.

The problem is, that this dynamic proxy has to implement (if you use interfaces) or extend (if the reference points to a concrete class) the class to be lazy-loaded. When the class is the superclass of a persistent hierarchy hibernate does not know which interface resp. class to implement.

Example:
You have persistent classes A, B, C, X, like this:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

class X {
   A a;
   getA() { return a;}
}
```

You tell hibernate to use lazy loading for attribute `a` in X.
Now you want to do something like this:

```
X x = ...; // load from DB
A a = x.getA();

if (a instanceof B) { ... }
else if (a instanceof C) { ... }
```

If `a`is loaded lazy, `x.getA()` will return a dynamic proxy. But how can hibernate know whether the proxy has to be a `B` or `C`? The only way is to actually load the relevant data from the database to check. And since it has to go to the DB anyway, it doesn't bother with a proxy, and just loads the complete object.

Comment: This seems of be a condition, I'm exploring few more ways to do it. Thanks